# Jaxb XML marshaling add prefix to root element

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling, xml-namespaces, prefix

I have follow problem, whem I am generating XML file Jaxb add prefix to namespace of root element and I don't know how to skip it.

I have package-info.java file

```
    @XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03", xmlns = {
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03", prefix = "")
}, elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

I have root element

```
    @XmlType(name = "Document",
        propOrder = {
                "cstmrCdtTrfInitn"
        })
@XmlRootElement(name = "Document")
public class Document {

        @XmlElement(name = "CstmrCdtTrfInitn", required = true)
        protected CustomerCreditTransferInitiationV03 cstmrCdtTrfInitn;
    }
```

And as result I got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Document xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
    <ns2:CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <ns2:GrpHdr/>
    </ns2:CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</ns2:Document>
```

without @XmlNs it work in same way,  adding namespace to @XmlRoolElement also doen't help.
What can be wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you  are trying achieve, your xml is matching your code perfectly fine.

If you don't want namespace at all:

```
<Document>
 <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
  <GrpHdr>ala</GrpHdr>
 </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document
```

simply change package info to

```
@XmlSchema()
```

If you want to use target namespace (so no prefix), like

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
 <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
  <GrpHdr>ala</GrpHdr>
 </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

then

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

all above tested with standard Java7 jaxb

Comment: exactly, but the problem I got xml with ns2: prefix

Comment: what is your jaxb provider. Was it a real example or is the document part of another one for example soap message.